# MySQL fulltext search only in selected rows

Tags: mysql, search

I have the following table:

|id| color  |text|
|1 | red    |lorem lipsum|
|1 | blue   |lorem lipsum|
|1 | green |lorem lipsum|
|2 | red     |lorem lipsum|
|3 | green |lorem lipsum|
|3 | red   |lorem lipsum|

And i have the following mysql query that works great to do a fulltext search on all text column rows:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST('search term')
```

Now the problem is that i want to be able to search only on the text rows where the color is for example red. Something like this(but of course it don't work):

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE color = 'red' AND MATCH (text) AGAINST('search term')
```

Comment: ***but of course it don't work*** doesn't makes any sense until you provide the explanation for actual error or any problem

Comment: Cannot find a problem here,seems to work fine for me:
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;
 CREATE TABLE `data`
 (`id` INT, `color` VARCHAR(5), `text` VARCHAR(20), FULLTEXT(`text`), PRIMARY KEY(`id`,`color`)) ENGINE = MYISAM
;
 
INSERT INTO `data`
 (`id`, `color`, `text`)
VALUES
 (1, 'red', 'Answer unknown'),
 (1, 'blue', 'text database'),
 (1, 'green', 'Answer unknown'),
 (2, 'red', 'Answer unknown'),
 (3, 'green', 'Answer unknown'),
 (3, 'red', 'text database')
;
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE color = 'red' AND MATCH (`text`) AGAINST('database');

Comment: Thanks a lot Giles! After setting color as primary key it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE color = 'red' AND text LIKE '% SEARCH TERM %'
```

Comment: Thanks but "LIKE" it's not enough for the kind of search i need.  Giles helped me, after setting color as primary key query worked.